# DBD::mysql installation of driver failed

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, perlbrew

I'm trying to run Perl DBI on Mac OS and keep hitting into this error:

> install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
>       Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 194.
>       at (eval 4) line 3.
>       Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 3.
>       Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
>       at test.pl line 12.

I've already tried to use perlbrew, ActivePerl, symlinks, but no luck.

**Fixed: for some reason DBI/DBD won't work with latest MySQL (8+) on mac. Downgrading to version 5 solves this problem.**

Comment: Do you have the MySQL libraries installed? I'm thinking the dev libraries. Not the Perl module, but the from-MySQL dev libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: for some reason DBI/DBD won't work with latest MySQL (8+) on mac. Downgrading to version 5 solves this problem.